# Is it possible in typescript to make a module that work like this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, callback

I would like to make a function / module / class that I can call in this way:

```typescript
const myvar = MyModule('a parameter').methodA().methodB().methodC();

//but also this should work

const myvar = MyModule('a parameter').methodC().methodA();
```

In other words, to make a static module that can accept a different number of "callback?" in any possible order.

I don't want to make an instance of the class and I would like that each method will return a string.

Is this even possible?

**EDIT**

To be more clear. I would like a way to process a string as an input with different methods. Each method process the string in a way and return the result to the next method. If there is no method attached it will return the string.

Maybe I am asking something impossible. But maybe exists something that has a similar structure and the same result.

Comment: What's the relationship between the two lines? Is `methodA` on the first line supposed to refer to the same function as `methodA` on the second line? If that's the case, under what circumstances do you want `methodA` to return a string and what circumstances an object with a `methodB` property?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear. I would like to append as many methods I want. And at the end I receive a string as a result of all this methods that have processed the string.

Comment: `And at the end` What indicates that we're "at the end"?

Comment: there are no other methods attached.

Comment: Do you expect the following two examples to have the same behavior or different behavior: `const myvar = MyModule('a parameter').methodC().methodA();` vs `const temp = MyModule('a parameter').methodC(); const myvar = temp.methodA()`? If they're supposed to behave differently, that's impossible.

Comment: it should have the same result indeed.

Comment: ok, then once again: what indicates that we're at the end? How can we know that there will never be another line of code that tries to add another call on?

Comment: would it be acceptable if there's a special function that indicates we're at the end? like `methodA().methodB().value()`, where `value` means "ok, that's enough, give me my string"?

Comment: That is exactly what I would like to know. My first idea was to make a method call "return" or "value" as you suggested. But I want to know if there is a way to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Ye it's kina possible, but without static class named `MyModule`, you need to add to `String` prototype new methods

```js
declare interface String {
  methodA(): string;
  methodB(): string;
}

String.prototype.methodA = function(this: string) {
  return this.toLowerCase() + 'Lower';
}

String.prototype.methodB = function(this: string) {
  return this.toUpperCase() + 'Upper';
}

console.log('hello'.methodA().methodB(), 'hello2'.methodB().methodA().methodB());
```

Output:

```
HELLOLOWERUpper HELLO2UPPERLOWERUpper
```

But I'm not sure it's what you expect

Comment: That would def work. But what if I don't want to extend String. I would like to make a static module instead. How would you develop it?

Answer (score 0):

Here i got one more solution, which is closest to the expected result

```js
function MyModule(str: string) {
  return {
    str,
    methodA() {
      this.str = this.str.toUpperCase() + '1';
      return this;
    },
    methodB() {
      this.str = this.str.toLowerCase() + '2';
      return this;
    },
    methodC() {
      this.str = str.substr(0, 4);
      return this;
    },
    toString() {
      return this.str;
    },
    valueOf() {
      return this.str;
    }
  }
}

const myvar = MyModule('a parameter').methodA().methodB().methodC();
const myvar2 = MyModule('a parameter2').methodB().methodA();
console.log(`myvar: ${myvar}`);
console.log(`myvar2: ${myvar2}`);
```

output:

```
myvar: a pa
myvar2: A PARAMETER221
```

But there is one problem, if you `console.log(myvar)` then you will see not the string, but the object. To reach your goal you will need to concat this variable with string, or just call `.toString()` method;

```
> console.log(myvar);
{
  str: 'a pa',
  methodA: [Function: methodA],
  methodB: [Function: methodB],
  methodC: [Function: methodC],
  toString: [Function: toString],
  valueOf: [Function: valueOf]
}

> console.log(myvar + myvar2);
a paA PARAMETER221

> console.log(myvar.toString());
a pa

> console.log('' + myvar);
a pa

> console.log(`${myvar}`);
a pa
```

Comment: Yes, I believe the only way is to have a function that return the value. What do you think about my solution? Thank you.

Comment: Under the hood it's very similar. Because you need to call 'return' method to get this string. But there is problem with your solution, you can process only one string at the moment, becasue you are working on singleton.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for now:

```typescript
export default class sanitize {

    private _var:any = '';

    private static _instance:sanitize;

    private constructor(){}

    private static _g(){
        return this._instance || (this._instance = new this());
    }
    public static return(){
        const ret = this._g()._var;
        this._g()._var = '';
        return ret;
    }
    private static return_class(){
        return this;
    }
    private static check_string(){
        if(typeof this._g()._var != 'string')
            this.string(this._g()._var);
    }
    public static string(variable:any){
        if(typeof variable.toString != undefined)
            this._g()._var = variable.toString();
        else
            this._g()._var = '';
        return this.return_class();
    }
    public static alphanum(){
        this.check_string();
        this._g()._var = this._g()._var.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
        return this.return_class();
    }
    public static tolow(){
        this.check_string();
        this._g()._var = this._g()._var.toLowerCase();
        return this.return_class();
    }
    public static toup(){
        this.check_string();
        this._g()._var = this._g()._var.toUpperCase();
        return this.return_class();
    }
    public static subs(start:number, end:number){
        this.check_string();
        this._g()._var = this._g()._var.substring(start, end);
        return this.return_class();
    }
}
```

```
// And then I call

const san_str = sanitize.string('could be a number').alphanum().tolow().return();
```